# The 'NCD.L1.sample--thanks' project not working as expected

Tags: nearprotocol

I've been following the example shown here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6JlZpYMvpo&list=PL9tzQn_TEuFXdfbkEw5_16Dsf0F6QLDmL&index=21&t=900s

The repo is here: 
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--thanks

As I tried to run `./scripts/1.dev-deploy.sh`, and this was returned:

[The Error Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsKWQ.png)

I'd love to know if I did anything wrong here and if so what the solution would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error about a missing dependency, I think you forgot to run `yarn`

I've updated the instructions to include this as step #2

```
## Usage

### Development

To deploy the contract for development, follow these steps:

1. clone this repo locally
2. run `yarn` to install dependencies
3. run `./scripts/1.dev-deploy.sh` to deploy the contract (this uses `near dev-deploy`)

**Your contract is now ready to use.**
```

Comment: That solved the problem :)) Thank you!